# Combining newcommand and renewcommand with optional arguments

Tags: macros

If I use

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3][\empty]{#1#2#3}
```

and want to renew those options by

```
\newcommand{\renewfoo}[2][\empty]{\renewcommand{\foo}[3][\empty]{???}}
```

What do I have to note instead of "???", if I want to use `#1` and `#2` of `\renewfoo` and still wants to keep `#1`,`#2`,`#3` of `\foo`?

Comment: I think you just need to double up the `#`. So instead of `#1` use `##1`.  Explanation: `#1` is be the first paramater to `\renewfoo` so `##1` is the first paramater to `\foo`.

Comment: `\newcommand{\renewfoo}[2][\empty]{\renewcommand{\foo}[3][#1]{This is from #2 and the internal ##1, ##2,##3}}` perhaps? But the use - case is not really clear

Comment: `\newcommand{\renewfoo}[2][\empty]{\renewcommand{\foo}[3][\empty]{##1, ##2 and ##3 from foo and #1 and #2 from renewfoo}}`

Comment: It's not really clear why not using `\renewcommand{\foo}` directly. What's the use of `\empty` for, by the way?

Comment: Ah nice. I didn't thought this would be the right way. @egreg \empty seems to be an old fragment of my tex-life. I used it often if I wanted to check \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}{}{}

Comment: Does anyone want to add an answere, so I can mark it as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(La)TeX` allows for nested (re)definition of macros, i.e. (re)definitions inside of other macros. In order to let `(La)TeX` distinguish between the (possible) arguments of the outer macro and the inner arguments, the number of argument specifiers `#` etc. has to be doubled for the inner macro, i.e. `#1`, `#2` becomes `##1`, `##2` etc.

If there is another level of nesting, the argument specifiers `#` has to doubled again, i.e.

First level: `#1`

Second level: `##1`

Third level: `####1`

Fourth level `########1`

etc. (Both more than three levels is weird), with other words: `2^{level-of-nesting-1}` occurences of the `#` character must be used.

I've added a version for `xparse` as well to get around the 'weird' `\empty` optional argument parameter. However, I don't suggest the redefinition a) with another wrapper and b) the wrapper having an optional argument as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\newcommand{\foo}[3][\empty]{%
  #1#2#3%
}

\newcommand{\renewfoo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\foo}[3][#1]{And now for something completely different: #2 and ##2##3[##1]}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{o+m+m}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1}%
  #2#3%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\RenewFooBar}{o+m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{O{#1}+m+m}{%
      And now for something completely different with xparse: #2 and ##2##3[##1]%
    }%
  }{%
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{+m+m}{%
      And now for something completely different with xparse: #2 and ##1##2%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\foo[A]{B}{C}

\renewfoo{\LaTeXe}

\foo[C]{A}{B}

\foobar{E}{F}

\foobar[D]{E}{F}

\RenewFooBar{Mr. Gumby}

\foobar{E}{F}


\RenewFooBar[Brain Surgeon]{Mr. Gumby}


\foobar{E}{F}



\end{document}
```